# How to get the docker-machine IP in Play With Docker (PWD) environment?

Tags: docker, pwd

I'm following the tutorial in https://docker-curriculum.com/. When I run a docker container with a static website (docker run -d -P --name static-site prakhar1989/static-site) I can't access the web application because I have not the IP address of the docker environment. How can I get the docker-machine IP in Play With Docker (PWD) environment?

Answer (score 0):

The instance IP address is all over the place in PWD, its even part of the command line as the root ssh. Is that not what you're looking for? Whenever you run a container and expose a port, PWD lets you click a button that opens a link to the ip:port